# WIX Installer - Validate return value from ExePackage

Tags: c#, sql, wix, installation, dism

I am running a number of `ExePackage`s in my WIX installer (custom GUI) that call DISM to download various components.  When internet is not available they fail but I am unable to tell the user why.  The WIX installer log reports appropriately what has happened.  Is there a way to access this information / the return value?

```
  <ExePackage InstallCommand="/qs /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=&quot;[INSTANCENAME]&quot; /SQLSVCACCOUNT=&quot;NT AUTHORITY\Network Service&quot; /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=&quot;[MACHINENAME]\[USERNAME]&quot; /AGTSVCACCOUNT=&quot;NT AUTHORITY\Network Service&quot; /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=&quot;[INSTANCEPASSWORD]&quot; /ENABLERANU=true /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=true"                  
                Id="SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
                Name="SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
                Cache="no"
                Compressed="no"
                PerMachine="yes"
                Permanent="yes"
                Vital="yes"
                SourceFile=".\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
                DownloadUrl="http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/B/04BE03CD-EAF3-4797-9D8D-2E08E316C998/SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
                SuppressSignatureVerification="yes"
                InstallCondition="CREATENEWINSTANCE"/>
```

Log:

> [04B8:06B8][2013-08-06T09:39:00]i338: Acquiring package:
>   SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe, payload: SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe, download from:
>   http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/B/04BE03CD-EAF3-4797-9D8D-2E08E316C998/SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe
>   [04B8:06B8][2013-08-06T09:39:45]e000: Error 0x80072efd: Failed to send
>   request to URL:
>   http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/B/04BE03CD-EAF3-4797-9D8D-2E08E316C998/SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe,
>   trying to process HTTP status code anyway.
>   [04B8:06B8][2013-08-06T09:39:45]e000: Error 0x80072efd: Unknown HTTP
>   status code 0, returned from URL:
>   http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/B/04BE03CD-EAF3-4797-9D8D-2E08E316C998/SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe